# How to use batch update in firestore web version-9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

In my nuxt project, I want to update some values in my firestore collection but i get mistakes

```
  const batch = writeBatch(firestore);

  const data = query(collection(firestore, `notifications`, `${uid}/news`));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(data);

  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.data().type === 'like') {
      batch.update(doc, { seen: true });
    }

     batch.commit();
  });
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: FirebaseError: A write batch can no longer be used after commit() has been called.    i want to mark all notifications seen in this method. batch method can be used easily in version-8 but i face with this mistake in ver-9

Comment: Note that you would get the same error in v8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `DocumentReference` as first argument of the `update()` method, and not a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`.

You also need to commit the batch outside of the loop: you can commit the batch only once. This is what indicates the error message you added as a comment to your question.

Finally, note that you don’t need to use the `query()` method since you want to loop over the entire collection.

```
 const batch = writeBatch(firestore);

 const data = collection(firestore, `notifications`, `${uid}/news`);

 const querySnapshot = await getDocs(data);

 querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
   if (doc.data().type === 'like') {
     batch.update(doc.ref, { seen: true });
   }
  });

  batch.commit();
```

Comment: yes it worked . my mistake was to use  batch.commit(); inside forEach .

Comment: See the update. I’ve just seen you your comment.